# Existence of projective curve such that...

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Is true that for any two different integers $d,d'>1$ there exist two projective curve, of degree $d$ and $d'$ that are not isomorphic and two projective curves that are birational ?

Comment: What have $d,d'$ to do with the projective curves you mention?

Comment: You are right sorry

Comment: Ok. I Have think about the first answer. I'm thinking about the projective closure of the affine curve $x^d+y^d+1$, that is nonsingular and for different $d,d'>1$ have different genus given from the formula $1/2(d-1)(d-2)$ so they are not isomorphic. Is this right ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to the second question is "yes".
Consider the affine curves given by the equations $y^n-x$ over some field $k$. Their function field $F$ is rational: $F=k(x,y)=k(y)$. Hence the projective closure of all of these curves is birational to $\mathbb{P}^1_k$.

However these projective closures are pairwise non-isomorphic: for $n>1$ the curves possess a singularity at $[1:0:0]$. This is the only singularity of these curves. As Matt pointed out the singularity is given by the equation $y^n=z^{n-1}$ and thus the local ring in the singularity is $O_n:=k[y,z]_{(y,z)}$. Since $y=(\frac{z}{y})^{n-1}$, $y$ is integral over $O_n$.

Claim: the ring $O:=O_n[\frac{z}{y}]$ is local and the integral closure of $O_n$ in $F$.

Proof: $O$ contains $k[\frac{z}{y}]$ and is therefore integrally closed, hence it is the integral closure of $O_n$. $(y,z)$ is the maximal ideal of $O_n$ and $(y,z)O=\frac{z}{y}O$. Consequently $O/(y,z)O=O_n/(y,z)$, that is $(y,z)O$ is the only maximal ideal of $O$ lying over $(y,z)$.

One concludes that $O$ is a discrete valuation ring. For the valuation $v$ attached to it one has $v(y)=n-1$ and $v(z)=n$. It follows that

$\mu_n:=\min (v(a) : a\in (y,z))=n-1$.

For isomorphic local rings $O_n$ the integral closures in $F$ are ismorphic and the numbers $\mu_n$ must therefore be equal. Thus the rings $O_n$ for $n>1$ cannot be isomorphic.

For $n=1$ the curve is regular.

Comment: Dear Hagen, If we change coordinates to put the point $[1:0:0]$ as the origin, then the singularity there has the equation $y^n = z^{n-1}$, which does not look like $n$ lines crossing, but rather is a cusp.  Regards,

Comment: Matt, you are right. I made a stupid mistake. I have to check whether the local rings are nevertheless pairwise non-isomorphic.

Comment: The composition of two birational morphism is still a birational morphism ?